# Term for 'x' in 'dx'

Tags: calculus, terminology

When writing derivatives in Leibniz notation, the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ can be written as $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

What is the mathematical term for the '$x$' in '$dx$', in the context of differentiation?

I need this information to properly name variables for a mathematics library that I am programming.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it is called the variable of differentiation